# Add bulk discount options to cart in Opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

Just wondering if there is a way that I can add discounts to the shopping cart in Opencart.

Basically im wanting customers to be able to select an option, i,e size, then add bulk amounts to the shopping cart. This would then add say 1000 of this item directly to the shopping cart. Im trying to get something like this:

Buy 1000 or more for only £5.00 per unit [Add to cart]

Buy 2000 or more for only £4.50 per unit [Add to cart]

Here is my code so far, unfortunatly Im not sure how to get this working correctly so any help would be great.

Thanks!

```
<?php if ($discounts) { ?>
<br />
<div class="discount">
  <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
  <div class="discount-item">
  <h3>Buy <?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?> or more for only <?php echo $discount['price']; ?></h3>
  <a onClick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're asking for. But if it's any help, the `addToCart` method that comes with the default template accepts an optional second field, which is the quantity. So you could do:

`<a onClick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', <?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?>);" class="button"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>`

Edit for items with options:

I'll assume you're on the product page, as you need to select the options somehow... now we could clone the whole function that submits the data to the cart. But I think this is easier to manage:

First, change the link to look like this:

`<a class="buy-bulk" data-quantity="<?php echo $discount['quantity']; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>`

Then add the following near the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buy-bulk').on('click', function() {
            var quantity = $(this).data('quantity');
            // change the quantity
            $('input[name="quantity"]').val(quantity);
            // simulate a click on the "add to cart button"
            $('#button-cart').trigger('click');
        })
    });
</script>
```

NOTE: untested! :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this response, its appreciated, however this function doesnt seem to work when an option is required. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah. So the whole addToCart idea kind of goes out the window. Let me edit my answer...

Comment: Thanks for this, however it doesnt seem to be responding. Im getting ReferenceError: buyBulk is not defined when i click the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Humm ok I'll edit again, was never keen on inline JS anyway haha